# Disable git add . command

Tags: git, git-add

Many times I mistakenly add unwanted files to the staging area using the `git add .` command.

I wonder if there is a way I could completely disable this command, so that I only use `git add file`?

Comment: If you mistakenly add some files you didn't want to, just use `git reset`, that will unstage everything.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: perhaps train yourself and get used to add "-u", as in: git add -u .

Comment: How come you keep typing `git add .<RETURN>` then?

Comment: @MicroVirus, I guess it is a bad habit from svn, which has a default to add only tracked files, where's git just takes everything.

Comment: alternatively one could add unwanted paths to gitignore

Comment: use git-gui so you can look at what you are doing..;)

Comment: There is also "git add -u" which just adds changes to tracked files; ignoring all untracked files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### SVN re-education

> I guess it is a bad habit from svn, which has a default to add only tracked files [...]

You must unlearn what you have learned :)

You should run `git status` often. If files you want to ignore get listed as untracked files, you should then edit your `.gitignore` file, so that those files actually become ignored. Because `git add` doesn't affect ignored (and untracked) files, you will then be able to use `git add .` to stage all files of interest (and only those) in one fell swoop.

### How to completely disable `git add .`

Git itself doesn't allow to do that, but if you really want to completely forbid the use of `git add .` (and `git stage .`, an exact equivalent), you can write a small wrapper around `git` (in your `~/.<shell>rc` file) for that:

```
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "add" -o "$1" = "stage" ]; then
        if [ "$2" = "." ]; then
            printf "'git %s .' is currently disabled by your Git wrapper.\n" "$1";
        else
            command git "$@";
        fi
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

Comment: +1 to fix this downvote, you provide a solution to the problem and also an explanation about the bad `SVN` habits

Comment: Hard to change bad habits (i was a pure TFS user before switching to git) but your remark is pertinent and it's very important to change these bad habits instead of searching for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

The important point about **`git add .`** is that it looks at the working tree and adds all those paths to the staged changes if they are either changed or are new and not ignored, it does not stage any 'rm' actions.

If I understand the question correctly, you simply want to "undo" the git add that was done for that file.

If that is the case, then

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

will do the job.

Your modifications will be kept and the file will once again show up in the modified, but not yet staged set of `git status`.

See the `git reset` man page for details.

Answer (score -1):

You should add all files and directories you do not want under version control to the .gitignore file.

If you only want to not add everything, well then, don't do git add .

Answer (score -1):

undo git add unstage remove git rm --cached filename.txt git delete from index cancel from commit
git reset filename.txt

Will remove a file named filename.txt from the current index, the "about to be committed" area, without changing anything else.

To undo git add . use git reset (no dot).

Comment: Copy-pasted from http://data.agaric.com/undo-git-add-remove-files-staged-git-commit

Comment: Please add the source in the answer and format it properly with code blocks.