# How can I stop myself from using 'git commit -a'?

Tags: git

I confess that I sometimes use `git commit -a` when I should not.  It's gotten to be reflex about half the time, often when I *think* I'm working in separate repositories - but I'm actually working in a much larger one that will affect directories far and wide.

Is there a `.git/config` setting I can specify that will cause the `-a` flag to throw an error?

Comment: None that I can see.  You could hack commit.c is about it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884007/disable-git-add-command/25886149#25886149

Comment: Could someone point me in the direction of something illustrating why -a is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a .git/config setting I can specify that will cause the -a flag to throw an error?

Not that I know of.

You would need a wrapper for git which would check the arguments ("`commit`", "`-a`", ...), and on the specific command "commit -a" would throw an error.

[Jubobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jubobs)' [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25886149/6309) (mentioned in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249924/how-can-i-stop-myself-from-using-git-commit-a/26252994#comment41178595_26249924)) is a good example of such a wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to VonC, I hacked up a function I stuck in my rc file:

```
git() {
    if [[ ($1 == "add") || ($1 == "stage") || ($1 == "commit") ]]; then
        if [[ $@ == *-a* ]]; then
            echo "Don't use 'git $1 -a'.";
        else
            command git "$@";
        fi
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. That looks fine. +1

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing in the  git configuration which will do this. However, there is a solution, and it's git hooks.

Git hooks are scripts which execute before or after a git command has been executed - for example, there's a hook which fails your commit if there's no commit message. So you can write a costum hook for your needs which falls when the commit is sloppy.

However, personally, I wouldn't fail it, but rather show an extra prompt (eg "Are you sure? Y/N"). Think about it, do you really want to block the functionality forever?

More info :
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Best of luck!

Comment: This would work if I had an easy way to detect a 'sloppy' commit, but putting that much logic in seemed wasteful when I could do it another, simpler way.  But thanks for the idea, it's a good one!