# Is it possible to create a warning when pushing to a specific (i.e. live) git source?

Tags: git, heroku, git-push

I run two Heroku servers, one dev and one production.  I set up Git with targets so I can do

```
git push dev ...
```

and

```
git push production ...
```

I push unfinished features that I'm testing all the time to the dev with

```
git push dev newBranch:master
```

I know that one of these days, when I'm tired, or overworked or just absent-minded, I'm going to mistakenly type

```
git push production newBranch:master
```

and push an untested, unworking feature to our live server and not realize it. Is there some way to build in a warning, so that, when I run

```
git push production
```

I get

> Warning, you are about to push to the live server, do you want to
>   continue (y/n)

or some other indication shows up on the screen?  I would sleep easier at night knowing a guard like that exists.

Comment: [Kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27066860/2541573) is right: you should use the `pre-push` hook for this. Alternatively, here is a dirty hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884007/disable-git-add-command/25886149#25886149

Answer (score 0):

You could use git's pre-push hook.

You can learn more about hooks [here,](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and you likely have example scripts installed with your git distribution (or even in your repo!)