# Can I make git reject an all-commit if I have before manually added files?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, git-add

Most of the time, I commit with `git commit -am`, because all I've done to the project belongs to the commit I'm working on.

Only sometimes, there are some changes I do not want to commit, so I use `git add -p` to stage only what I really want. Trouble is, I'm so used to typing `git commit -am` that I usually end up doing it anyway. I then get a commit with stuff I didn't want, and have to laborously go back to `HEAD^`, and also re-do the `add -p`.

Clearly, when some changes have already been added manually, `commit -am` doesn't make sense anymore. Is there a way to prevent git from accepting the option in this case (or some alternative to `-am` that is just as convenient)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script file, `git-cm`, and put it in your PATH

```
#!/bin/sh

DIRTY=$(git status -s| grep -e "^[A-Z]")
if [ ! "$DIRTY" ]; then
    git commit "$@";
    exit 0;
else 
    echo "Rejected, files already manually added";
    exit 1;
fi
```

run this when you want to commit

```
git-cm -am "some message"
```

if you already have files manually added the script will reject the commit and abort the operation.

This is because in this case, `git status -s` yields a line starting with e.g.

```
M  file/Ive/just.added`
```

where without manual adding it's

```
 M file/Ive/just.added
```

instead (notice the leading space).

You may need to adapt according to your environment.

Comment: That `egrep '^[A-Z]'` seems an awful hack, but oh well... it does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: One has to remember to use `git-cm` instead of `git`... How does that help, when one is already trying to remember not to use a certain command? Anyway, you may want to add the `--porcelain` flag to your `git status` command, for improved robustness.

Answer (score 0):

*Easier, quicker, more seductive.* As tempting as `git commit -am` may be, you should train yourself to stay away from it. It's really meant for very simple (e.g. single-file) commits. Use the staging area to your advantage: take the time to [compose the shot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352119/2541573) before you take a snapshot.

If this admonition isn't enough, and you need a little help to avoid `git commit -am`... Well, unfortunately, the Git API itself doesn't provide an easy way of "forbidding" a subset of its commands. One not very robust way, but that mostly does the trick, is to write a simple shell wrapper function for `git` that keeps an eye out for command-line arguments `commit` and `-am`, and takes measures when those arguments are used (same strategy as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25886149/2541573).):

```sh
# Git wrapper forbidding 'git commit -am'
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "commit" -a "$2" = "-am" ]; then
        printf "'git commit -am' is currently disabled by your Git wrapper.\n";
    else
        command git "$@";
    fi;
}
```

Depending on your habits, you can of course refine this wrapper to make it more robust.

Comment: Another approach would be to add a pre-commit hook that asks for confirmation, but I don't think there is a way of telling that hook that the `-am` flag was used.

Comment: I'm afraid if it weren't for `-am`, my hands would just get used to type `git add . && git commit -m`, and I'd have the same problem again.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "Bad habits" die hard. Unless you're ready to edit the Git source and build yourself a custom version, I can't think of any other way than that outlined in my answer, though.